# Redirects with .htaccess stops images from loading

Tags: php, regex, apache

OK So I'm looking to redirect the following:

> http://www.example.org/tag/code

To the following:

> http://www.example.org/tag.php?tag=code

The following regex is a mix of some of the answers to this question which solves the issue:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.+)/ $1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule (.+)/(.+) $1?tag=$2 [L,NC]
```

However now, when I try and load an image from my server which is within the directory `http://www.example.org/img/imagename.png`. It gives me a `500 Internal Server Error` and when checking the logs I'm given this message:

> [Wed Feb 23 12:27:27 2011] [error]
>   [client xx.xx.xx.xx] mod_rewrite:
>   maximum number of internal redirects
>   reached. Assuming configuration error.
>   Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to
>   increase the limit if neccessary.

Does anyone know what's going on there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above your `RewriteRule` add these 2 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These will tell mod_rewrite to ignore actual files and directories.  This should fix your /img/ problem.

You shouldn't need `RewriteCond $1 (^/include/)` with these lines.

To fix the `/img` folder, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^file/img/(.*)$ /img/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks thats great! However I still get the issue of when I goto example.org/file/something all the images are now example.org/file/img/img.png rather than example.org/img/img.png!

Comment: @ing0: Try adding a rule to rewrite the images.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
RewriteRule (.+?)/(.+) $1.php?t=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hey, this gives me a Apache Internal Server Error page :/

Comment: It makes it lazy.  I.e. if your string was `a/b/c` and you tried to match `(.+)/(.+)` then $1 = `a/b` and $2 = `c`.  If you do `(.+?)/(.+)` then $1 = `a` and $2 = `b/c`.

Comment: Maybe it needs the trailing slash?  Try `RewriteRule (.+?)/(.+)/ $1.php?t=$2 [L,NC]`?  What's the Apache error_log say?

Comment: /var/chroot/home/content/-------/.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '(.+?)/(.+)'\n

Comment: I'm also getting mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary. When I don't include the ? or trailing /

Comment: Sounds like it's entering an infinite loop.

Comment: So one Rewrite is affecting the other to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule (.+)/(.+) $1.php?t=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule (.+)/ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This also gives me Internal Server Error :( However only when I goto /file/whatevers

Comment: Just posted them on the other answer!